# AVAudioPlayer Gets Quieter

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I'm using avaudioplayer to play some sounds, and I want it to stop when a function runs. I'm using `stop()`, and it happens, but then when I play it again, it's a ton quieter. The next time around it's barely audible. I'm not messing with the volume at all. Is this a common problem?

Comment: Include the code so people can help debug it.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use `pause()` instead of `stop()`?